# using the concept of loop in ajax or extjs4

Tags: ajax, extjs4

I want to add the concept of **loop**  in my jsp file

I work with extjs 4

I have a textField , in this field I should enter a text ,

my goals is after the caractere number five , a query will be runned and will retreive a data from database ( this data is the list of emplyees which corresponds to entered data in the textfield

so the textfield will be like a **combobox** ( meaning that will contain a list of emplyees )

I think that this concept will work with **Ajax**

currently  I have this code :

```
xtype: 'textfield',
fieldLabel: 'test',
id: 'nameEmployee',
flex: 1,
margin: '5 5 5 5',
allowBlank : false,
blankText: ' champs oligatoire',
```

but I think that the type will be combobox  like :

```
xtype: 'combobox',
store: employerComboStore,
displayField: 'label',
valueField: 'value',
queryMode: 'local',
fieldLabel: 'test',
id: 'nameEmployee',
allowBlank : false,
margin: '5 5 5 5',
blankText: 'champs obligatoire',
flex: 1
```

So I should develop a code in **ajax** which run a query a retreive a data according to data entered in the textField

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be much easier to just use a `ComboBox` and set the `hideTrigger` config. It looks exactly like a text field, but behaves with the drop down list like the Combo.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I think that I should use ajax, because it is the best solution to send request and have answer from databse ,

Comment: The combo already does that. Look at the `queryMode` parameter. When you type it fires off a request to the server.

Comment: also I think you for this answer, but if is possible , can you give me an example with this concept, meaning example using hideTrigger  and queryMode